# Algorithm help: how to divide array into N segments with least possible largest segment (balanced segmenting)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

I came across this problem on one of the russian programming forums, but haven't come up with an elegant solution.

**Problem:**

You have an array with **N positive integers**, you need to divide it into **M contiguous segments**, so that the total of the largest segment is the smallest possible value. By segment's total, I mean the sum of all its integers. In other words, I want a well-balanced array segmentation, where you don't want a single segment to be too large.

**Example:**

- Array: [4, 7, 12, 5, 3, 16]
- M = 3, meaning that I need to divide my array into 3 subarrays.
- Solution would be:  [4,7] [12, 5] [3, 16]  so that the largest segment is [3, 16] = 19 and no other segmentation variant can produce the largest segment with smaller total.

**Another example:**

- Array [3, 13, 5, 7, 18, 8, 20, 1]
- M = 4

Solution: [3, 13, 5] [7, 18] [8] [20, 1], the "fattest" segment is [7, 18] = 25 (correct me if I am wrong, I made up this example)

I have a feeling that this is some classic CS/math problem, probably with some famous person's name associated with it, like Dijkstra's problem.
 - Is there any known solution for it?
 - If not, can you come up with some other solution besides brute forcing, which is, as far as I understand time complexity, **exponential.** (N^M, to be more specific).

Thanks in advance, stackoverflowers.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Jordan why? The [StackOverflow help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says you can ask about _a software algorithm_. The [Programmers help](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says you can ask about _algorithm and data structure concepts_. I could see this question fitting either site.

Comment: If this is a homework question you should show some code and basic own research (as of site definition). It does sound like the knappsack problem, btw.

Comment: sounds like the painters problem: http://leetcode.com/2011/04/the-painters-partition-problem.html

Comment: @Vic I read the article, it is actually the same problem, wrapped in a real life example. Thanks.

Comment: @eckes It is probably a variation of knapsack problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [ILoveCoding's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28095738/47984).  Here's another way that takes **O(MN^2) time**, which will be faster if N and M are small but the numbers in the array are very large (specifically, if log(sum) >> MN, which is possible but admittedly doesn't sound very realistic).  It uses dynamic programming.

Let's consider partitioning just the subarray consisting of the first i <= N entries into j <= M segments.  Let f(i, j) be the weight of the largest segment in the best solution for this subproblem -- i.e. the weight of the largest segment in that j-partition of the first i numbers whose largest segment is smallest among all such partitions.  We want to compute f(N, M), as well as a (there may be more than one) partition that corresponds to it.

It's easy to compute f(i, 1) -- that's just the sum of the first i elements:

```
f(i, 1) = x[1] + ... + x[i]
```

To compute f(i, j) for j >= 2, observe that element i must be the final element of some segment that starts at some position 1 <= k <= i, and which is preceded by j-1 segments -- *and in any optimal solution for parameters (i, j), those j-1 preceding segments must themselves be optimal for parameters (k-1, j-1)*.  So if we consider every possible start position k for this final segment and take the best, we will calculate the best j-partition of the first i elements:

**[EDIT 3/2/2015: We need to take the max of the new segment and the largest remaining segment, instead of adding them!]**

```
f(i, j >= 2) = minimum of (max(f(k-1, j-1), x[k] + ... + x[i])) over all 1 <= k <= i
```

If we try k values in decreasing order, then we can easily build up the sum in constant time per k value, so calculating a single f(i, j) value takes O(N) time.  We have MN of these values to compute, so the total time needed is O(MN^2).

One more boundary condition is needed to forbid trying to partition into more segments than there are elements:

```
f(i, j > i) = infinity
```

Once we have calculated f(N, M), we could extract a corresponding partition by tracing back through the DP matrix in the usual way -- but in this case, it's probably easier just to build the partition using ILoveCoding's greedy algorithm.  Either way takes O(N) time.

Answer (score 5):

1. Let's do a binary search over the answer.
2. For a fixed answer `X`  it is easy to check if it is feasible or not(we can just use a greedy algorithm(always taking the longest possible segment so that its sum is `<= X`) and compare the number of segments to `M`).

The total time complexity is `O(N * log(sum of all elements))`.

Here is some pseudo-code

```
boolean isFeasible(int[] array, long candidate, int m) {
    // Here goes the greedy algorithm.
    // It finds the minimum number of segments we can get(minSegments).
    ...
    return minSegments <= m;
}

long getMinimumSum(int[] array, int m) {
    long low = 0; // too small
    long high = sum of elements of the array // definitely big enough
    while (high - low > 1) {
         long mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
         if (isFeasible(array, mid, m))
             high = mid;
         else
             low = mid;
    }
    return high;
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer? I didn't uderstand the binary part, array isn't sorted and isn't allowed to be.

Comment: Nice.  A minor optimisation: if you ever find yourself trying a value X that is less than SUM/M, you can skip the O(N) greedy pass for that iteration and immediately conclude that that X is too low, since in *any* partition of SUM into M parts, there must be at least one part >= SUM/M.

Comment: How do you show that the greedy algorithm is optimal?