# Could not understand "painter partition "

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have gone through the painters partition problem (http://articles.leetcode.com/2011/04/the-painters-partition-problem-part-ii.html) . but could not get it. could any one please describe it. particularly i am not able to understand "Find the `index j` such that `B[j]` fails to satisfy the condition while `B[j+1]` satisfy"

Comment: there is another explanation :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095662/algorithm-help-how-to-divide-array-into-n-segments-with-least-possible-largest

Comment: I got it last night.  Will try to explain it in near future.