# Minimizing cost

Tags: python, sorting

There are groups and P items. The cost taken by each group for each item is given in a 2D List. I want to solve this problem by minimizing the cost and by adding all the items.

```
for effort in items:
    minE = min(minE , sum(effort))

row = len(items)
col = len(items[0])

itemsEach = []
for i in range(col):
    minm = items[0][i]
    for j in range(1 , row):
        if items[j][i] < minm:
            minm = items[j][i]
    itemsEach.append(minm)
minE = min(minE , sum(itemsEach))
print(minE)
```

Comment: How many doctors and patients can there be?

Comment: This question is part of an ongoing contest . The person posting the problem is violating code of conduct. I request the moderator to take down the associated problem and not to discuss it further .Techgig codegladiators semi final round1
https://www.techgig.com/codegladiators . The problem is active till july 6th for submissions

Answer (score 2):

Edit: This answer is for the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62589889/1).

Here is one way to solve it:

```
from functools import lru_cache


def min_cost(costs) -> int:
    num_doctors = len(costs)
    num_patients = len(costs[0])

    @lru_cache(None)
    def doctor_cost(doctor_index, patient_start, patient_end) -> int:
        if patient_start >= patient_end:
            return 0
        return costs[doctor_index][patient_start] + doctor_cost(
            doctor_index, patient_start + 1, patient_end
        )

    @lru_cache(None)
    def min_cost_(patient_index, available_doctors) -> float:
        if all(not available for available in available_doctors) or patient_index == num_patients:
            return float("+inf") if patient_index != num_patients else 0

        cost = float("+inf")
        available_doctors = list(available_doctors)
        for (doctor_index, is_doctor_available) in enumerate(available_doctors):
            if not is_doctor_available:
                continue

            available_doctors[doctor_index] = False
            for patients_to_treat in range(1, num_patients - patient_index + 1):
                cost_for_doctor = doctor_cost(
                    doctor_index, patient_index, patient_index + patients_to_treat
                )
                cost = min(
                    cost,
                    cost_for_doctor
                    + min_cost_(
                        patient_index + patients_to_treat, tuple(available_doctors)
                    ),
                )
            available_doctors[doctor_index] = True

        return cost

    return int(min_cost_(0, tuple(True for _ in range(num_doctors))))


assert min_cost([[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 1, 2, 3]]) == 8
```

The `min_cost_` function takes a patient index and doctors that are available and assigns a doctor starting at that patient index and handling one or more patients (`patients_to_treat`).  The cost of this is the cost of the current doctor handling these patients (`doctor_cost`) + min_cost_(the next patient index with the current doctor being unavailable). The cost is then minimized over all available doctors and over the number of patients a doctor can treat.

Since there will be repeated sub-problems, a cache (using the `lru_cache` decorator) is used to avoid re-computing these sub-problems.

### Time complexity

Let `M` = number of doctors and `N` = number of patients.

The time complexity *across all calls to* `doctor_cost` is `O(M * N^2)` since that is the number of `(doctor_index, patient_start, patient_end)` tuples that can be formed, and the function itself (apart from recursive calls) only does constant work.

The time complexity `min_cost_` is `O((N * 2^M) * (M * N)) = O(2^M * M * N^2)`. `N * 2^M` is the number of `(patient_index, available_doctors)` pairs that can be formed, and `M * N` is the work that the function (apart from recursive calls) does. `doctor_cost` can be considered O(1) here since in the calcuation of time compelxity of `doctor_cost` we considered *all possible calls to* `doctor_cost`.

Thus, the total time complexity is `O(2^M * M * N^2) + O(M * N^2) = O(2^M * M * N^2)`.

Given the constraints of the original problem (<= 20 patients, and <= 10 doctors), the time complexity seems reasonable.

### Other notes:

- There are some optimizations to this code that can be made that I've omitted for simplicity:

  - To find the optimal number of patients for a doctor, I try as many consecutive patients as I can (i.e. the `patients_to_treat` loop). Instead, the optimal number of patients could be found by binary search. This will reduce the time complexity of `min_cost_` to `O(N * 2^M * M * log(N))`.
  - The `doctor_cost` function can be calculated by storing the prefix-sum of each row of the `costs` matrix. i.e. instead of the row `[2, 3, 1, 2]` store `[2, 5, 6, 8]`. This will reduce the time complexity of `doctor_cost` to `O(M * N)`.
  - The list of available doctors (`available_doctors`) could be a bit field (and since number of doctors <= 10, a 16 bit integer would suffice)
- This question is quite similar to the [painter's partition problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095662/algorithm-help-how-to-divide-array-into-n-segments-with-least-possible-largest) with the added complexity of different costs for a doctor to treat a patient.
- Run [this repl](https://repl.it/repls/WiltedPapayawhipNanotechnology#main.py) for a visualization of what the algorithm picks as an optimal solution.

Comment: I think if we follow painter's partition algorithm, the time complexity will be O(2^n * n!  * n^2)

Comment: @chindiralasampathkumar I calculated the time complexity to be `O(2^M * M * N^2)` where `M = #doctors` and `N = #patients`. I've added a section in the solution explaining.

Comment: Regarding time complexity I have a doubt. Whether it is 2^M or M!?. I have written code just to call AvailableDoctors method for Number of Doctors = 10, it is making around 10M  calls. https://repl.it/repls/VariableSuperbExams#main.cs

Comment: In your repl, `DoctorsAvailable()` is not cached, but in the Python code above the `@lru_cache(None)` decorator caches the result of the function call. If we take this into account, `min_cost_` will only be called at-most `N*2^M` times

Comment: Yes, you are right. After adding cache calls have been reduced significantly.  It is a great learning for me. Thank you once again!.